# JSP pages and mysql database connection disconnects after an unknown period of time (about 2 days)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat

I am working on JSP and MySQL.
After uploading my project on the online server (webfaction), it works fine. However, after one day or two, the pages lost the connection with the database, so when I try to login for example it does not connect to the databases, although the JSP pages and Tomcat are running fine.

However, when I restart Tomcat, the connection works fine for one or two days, and then the issue happens again.

Here is the class for connection:

```
package Connect_DB;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbConnect {

    public final static int delayPeriod = 500; 
    public final static String driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    public final static String mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";  
    private static final String dbName = "mydatabase?characterEncoding=UTF-8";   
    private static final String dbUser = "root"; 
    private static final String dbPassword = "";  

    private static Connection con = null;

    public static Connection getConnection(String db, String user, String password) {
        String dbUrl = mysqlUrl + db;
         con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driverClassName);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();       
        }


        return con;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        if(con == null){
            return getConnection(dbName, dbUser, dbPassword);
        }else{
            return con;
        } 
    }
}
```

And the following is the (Model) class for all functions to communicate with the database:

```
package Connect_DB.allghamees;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchDb {

    public Connection con;

    public SearchDb(Connection con) {
        this.con = con;
    }

    public boolean checkMobileAndPassword(String mobile, String pass) throws SQLException {
        boolean ok = false;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement queryEmaiPass= null;

        try {

            String sqlQuery = "SELECT mobile, password FROM users WHERE mobile = ? and password = ?";
            queryEmaiPass = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            queryEmaiPass.setString(1, mobile);
            queryEmaiPass.setString(2, pass);
            rs = queryEmaiPass.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                ok = true;                
            }
            rs.close();
            queryEmaiPass.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } 

        return ok;
    }
```

The following JSP page sample is to call the above class once the connection is needed:

```
<%@page import="org.joda.time.DateTime"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="DB_Connect.allghamees.Activities"%>
<%@page import="DB_Connect.allghamees.Users"%>
<%@page import="DB_Connect.DbConnect"%>
<%@page import="DB_Connect.allghamees.SearchDb"%>
<%@page import="DB_Connect.allghamees.Validator1"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:include page="headPage.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <title>Project 25</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>

<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
<%

SearchDb db = new SearchDb(DbConnect.getConnection());
        int typeId = 0;
        String mobile = request.getParameter("mobile");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

        boolean  checkMobilePassword = false;
        checkMobilePassword = db.checkMobileAndPassword(mobile, pass);

try {

if (!checkMobilePassword) {
                session = request.getSession(true);
              session.setAttribute("userLogin", 2);
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }

}
  catch (Exception ex) { 
            //out.close();
        }

%>                
</html>
```

One of the requirements to upload on the Webfaction server is JAVA class should be complied on JDK 6, and I did so.

Can you help me why this happens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am very impressed that the connection stays up for so long. Generally, you are supposed to only keep the connection open for a reasonably short amount of time, and release it when you don't use it.

Having said that, there's connection pooling — basically the same technique you use here: you grab a connection and use it while it's up. Now when you use pooling, it is advisable to check the connection before re-using and reopen one if it's not alive any more.

Answering your question, most probably it's due to a prolonged silence from the JSP side; if you're not using the connection, the server will close it. If you would like to find out more, enable detailed logging on both MySQL side and in the MySQL drivers, and you'll see (1) what exactly closes the connection, and, hopefully, (2) why.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I read that the ResultSet, PrepStat and Conn should be closed when using the pool connection, otherwise there will be a leak in the db connection that results in losing the connection between the db and server. However, when I tried to apply that by typing close the Conn after closing the ResultSet and PrepStat I got an error. Can you advise that how I should close the connection based on the given code above? Thanks

Comment: I guess that should be either a separate question with full details, ie code plus the exception you're getting — or an edit on the current question. I cannot guess what's wrong without details. Usually you close connection just by `.close()`; if the connection was pooled, it turns to the pool. My best guess would be, you need to re-request the connection next time rather than saving it (as it's now "closed")